# inappurchase apple id login alert Listen for the "Cancel' button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to figure out how I can listen to the "Cancel" button that appears in the "Apple ID Password" alert shown when a user tries to purchase something. You know, the official one done by Apple, looks something like: "Apple ID Password. [username] [password] [Cancel] [OK]"

my flow is user already purchased and another time purchase restore transactions to login test user in sandbox environment `- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` method  doesn't called transaction failed when test user login alert canceled!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code for cancel button listener:

Your problem is during `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];`
restore completed transactions when user login alert click to cancel SKPaymentQueue restore transactions failed with error method occurs,use following code to help ful:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"<><Canceled!><>");
}
```

this method occur's user login alert cancel button!

welcome!